# Show Facebook Page Like Button in Phonegap

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins

How to show Facebook page like button in Phonegap Application?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use facebook SDK to make it works. You need to download these to files before add to your project.

Facebook SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/

Import into your eclipse. Then you can find a lot of samples inside it.

Comment: Is that mean I need to create plugin?

Comment: It depends on yr requirment.

Comment: I am getting to much confused sir....... I want Like button on my html page in Phonegap. when I click on it, then it should like that particular page only.

Comment: Please see this link................    https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/378#issuecomment-38137968    and   https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/344187825719434/

Answer (score -2):

Of course it is, you just need to get the like button,

somewhere like this for example :

[Facebook Like Icon](http://www.iconsdb.com/royal-azure-blue-icons/facebook-like-icon.html/)

and put it in your HTML page.
You'll see the button ;)
regards.

Comment: We all know he can, but how? can you post an example?

Answer (score -3):

Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening  tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="@your page-url to like@" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

It's that easy.

Comment: With this code you can add a facebook-like button for every page, it doesn't matter it is in PhoneGap or not.